# Python .ipynb file prints output to the terminal without print function .py doesnt

Tags: python, ipynb

I am implementing a sample probability density function. Although there is no print function in my code it prints sample output from my value. I use .ipynb file, and when i copy the code into .py file, it is not printed. I don't understand where is the problem. Here is my code:

```
import numpy as np

def gen_b():
    
    samples = []
    num_samples = 10000
    
    while len(samples) < num_samples:
        b = np.random.random() * 6
        y = np.random.random()
        if y <= pdf_b(b):
            samples.append(b)
    
    return samples

gen_b()
```

`pdf_b(x)` is a simple `f(x) = y`  function, there is no printing function inside of it.

How can i solve the problem? I don't want to sample output is printed. Here is the output that I don't want to be printed:

```
[2.140133171853366,
 3.782237422460611,
 4.252458824774285,
 1.9767482772032179,
 2.250855035249897,
 4.788930465436959,
 1.9076515188916072,
 2.745557799097914,
 3.620720920902893,
 2.540311807348857,
 3.3786579434452295,
 4.654430681635432,
 3.885627334171001,
 3.03255430392689,
 2.078660750831954,
 1.563168692059776,
 4.066738029089566,
 4.173320782327262,
 2.3957708748717117,
 2.392456670794856,
 2.0479422380490147,
 3.0472011553416785,
 1.2691569709730193,
 2.930679937209872,
 3.0627475835692044,
...
 2.3660255564569264,
 2.3079729976179957,
 2.8430403284524752,
 3.9573097908844583,
 ...]
Output is truncated. View as a scrollable element or open in a text editor. Adjust cell output settings...
```

Comment: Why are you even running `gen_b` at all, if you're not saving the output anywhere and you don't want to print it?

Comment: Sorry, it was my mistake. I'm supposed to save the sample output. But it is my first time coding in .ipynb file, i tried to check if there is a error in the function and run `gen_b`. I was confused when the output is printed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IPython **is a REPL**, a *read, evaluate, **print*** loop. The last statement that is evaluated is `gen_b()`, so the value is *printed*. If you don't want it printed, one thing you can do is to simply assign the result to something, even a throwaway variable, `_ = gen_b()` (or just don't run it in a REPL).